# Transformation optimizing stationarity of the residual of a regression

Tags: regression, data-transformation, residuals, stationarity

I am trying to define an objective function or a method to find the transformation and coefficients optimizing the stationarity of regression's residuals.

For instance, if I want to regress $X_1$ vs $X_2$ and I use a Box Cox transform. I want to find $\lambda$ and $\beta$ s.t. $\varepsilon = \frac{X_1^\lambda-1}{\lambda} - \beta*\frac{X_2^\lambda-1}{\lambda}$ is stationary.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you really seek a common transformation of *both* the independent and dependent variable? This is so extremely unusual that it would be interesting and useful to know why.

Comment: I am puzzled too. Is there any particular reason to apply the transformation to both DV and IV and if so why must the lambdas be the same.  Why would you leave out an intercept term? Why is stationarity of the residuals your goal as opposed to uncorrelated or independent?

Comment: Ideally the transform will be the same but it is not that important. In statistical arbitrage in finance the goal is to have a mean reverting/stationary spread to be able to trade systematically. In my example, X1 and X2 variances increase as their values increase. The transform serve has a variance stabilizer, thus making epsilon stationary. My idea is to have a classical mean square error penalized by some non-stationary cost. But I have not figured out how to do that.